# how to get attribute_set_id in magento 2 custom collection

Tags: collection, grid, attribute-set

I have created custom table and display the values as grid in admin by UI component.In my custom table already I have SKU column .now I need attribute set id Name of the product in custom grid .how to get attribute setid by joining in collection.what are the tables needs to be joined to get attribute set_id name ?

Comment: Please share your code what you have tried.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Collection.php which you are using for the Grid add below function code

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()
        ->columns('eas.attribute_set_name')
        ->join(
            ['cpe' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],
            'main_table.sku = cpe.sku',
            []
        )->join(
            ['eas' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_set')],
            'cpe.attribute_set_id = eas.attribute_set_id',
            []
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understand your issue. To give you a strict answer the attribute set is stored in the table `eav_attribute_set` where you can find the columns `attribute_set_id` and `attribute_set_name`

Now if what you try to do is add that value into a grid, we need more information and code about what you've done.